# How do I use ImageReader.abort()?

Tags: java, multithreading, javax.imageio

I'm loading potentially large images using a [javax.imageio.ImageReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) for thumbnail generation in a GUI, and when the user navigates to a different folder (on the Swing thread) I'd like to be able to interrupt the thumbnail generator's thread without waiting for the current image to finish loading. So I try calling the ImageReader's `abort()` method. But every time, I get this complaint:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to use instance of com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader@18e8541 locked on thread Thread[Thumbnail generator,2,main] from thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.setThreadLock(JPEGImageReader.java:1491)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.abort(JPEGImageReader.java:1285)
    at ThumbnailGenerator.setDoWork(ThumbnailGenerator.java:81)
    at FileList.navigateTo(FileList.java:93)
    at App.navigateTo(App.java:199)
    at App.navigateUp(App.java:207)
    at App$EventListener.keyPressed(App.java:234)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:233)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6246)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2801)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6065)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1850)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:712)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:990)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:855)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:676)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4523)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I'm confused. If you can't call `abort()` from a *different* thread, how are you ever supposed to call it at all? (The docs say the abort state is cleared when it starts loading an image.) I've also tried `thread.interrupt()` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call abort() inside of your own IIOReadProgressListener.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/imageio/spec/apps.fm7.html

Of course deferring till later might still prove useful, as I suspect the response will not happen immediately:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... });
```

Comment: I was just about to answer the same :)

Comment: I'm now setting an `abortWanted` flag in the Swing thread and checking for it then calling `abort()` inside `IIOReadProgressListener.imageProgress`. Thank you, this works perfectly!